Getting Block Height Exceed Errors when try to mint NFT using metaplex
I am trying to mint NFTs using metaplex, but I am getting errors - "Block height exceeded".
I tried to add priority fee to tx, but at metaplex functions I cannot find that option.
How to solve this?
